# plot line only in the current year in Pinescript

Tags: pine-script

I'm doing an indicator for tradingview and I want to plot the result only in the current year...

```
e = ema(close, 21)
plot(e)
```

what I want is something like:

```
plot( is_current_year ? e : na )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use something like that:

```
//@version=3
study("Plot current year")

isCurrentYear = year(timenow) == year(time)
plot(isCurrentYear ? close : na)
```

Comment: Works fine, Thank you.